# Make UIStepper increase increment by 5

Tags: ios, xcode, nsinteger, uistepper

Is there a way to make a UIStepper count by 5's rather than a single increment at a time? i.e, tap + and a label says 5, 10, 15, 20, etc. or subtract by 5 every time? So far I have tried `value +5;` and that doesn't work. Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `[<insertsteppername> setStepValue:5];`

For example:

```
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,20,0,0)];
[stepper setStepValue:5];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an increment setting (called 'step') for the UIStepper - you can find it in the Property Inspector.